# double quote issue in powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass installation arguments to a variable in powershell but I get errors doing that.

```
$InstallString = "$InstallLocation\application.exe" /install / quiet CID="BsDdfi3kj" Tag="CinarCorp"
```

I tried to run this as putting "&" symbol but it didn't work and I checked many websites but I couldn't solve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: where did you position the `&` ? Could you share an example using it ?

Comment: Added just before "$InstallLocation...." line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax used to the right of `=` only works when directly calling the command like this:

```
& "$InstallLocation\application.exe" /install /quiet CID="BsDdfi3kj" Tag="CinarCorp"
```

Note that you had a spurious space character before `quiet` which I removed.

Change the syntax like this when you actually want to store the command in a variable:

```
$InstallString = "`"$InstallLocation\application.exe`" /install /quiet CID=`"BsDdfi3kj`" Tag=`"CinarCorp`""
```

I have enclosed the whole string within double-quotes and escaped the inner double-quotes by placing a backtick in front of them.

You could also use a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings) to avoid having to escape the inner double-quotes:

```
$InstallString = @"
"$InstallLocation\application.exe" /install /quiet CID="BsDdfi3kj" Tag="CinarCorp"
"@
```

Note that the actual string as well as the final `"@` have to start at the beginning of the line. If you indent the actual string, the spaces/tabs are included in the variable, which is usually not wanted.

You could of course [trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0) the string if you insist on indentation:

```
$InstallString = @"
    "$InstallLocation\application.exe" /install /quiet CID="BsDdfi3kj" Tag="CinarCorp"
"@.Trim()
```

I recommend to read [about Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for further details.